# How to make a Rails application render the HTML generated by the ckeditor gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I installed the ckeditor gem:

https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor

I followed all the steps and I'm displaying it like this:

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.cktext_area :content, :input_html => { :value => "Default value" } %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tag_name %>
    <%= f.autocomplete_field :tag_name, autocomplete_tag_name_posts_path, :"data-delimiter" => ' ' %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and this is how I show the content:

```
<p><%= @post.content %></p><br />
```

But the output are the actual HTML tags. For instance:

```
<p> Default v<strong>al</strong>ue s<u>ada</u>sd</p>
```

How can I make it so that it actually renders the final HTML?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails escapes the output by default so you have to use raw:

```
<p><%= raw @post.content %></p>
```

Be careful using raw though, it'll open you up to XSS attacks if you're allowing untrusted users to output HTML on your site.

Comment: Thanks. So what is the usual thing to do in order to avoid XSS attacks in this kind of situations?

Comment: To be honest, I've never had a situation where I've allowed users to enter HTML so I'm not 100% sure of the best thing to do. Using the [sanitize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html) helper to whitelist only the absolutely necessary HTML elements/attributes should suffice though.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, thing went wrong in my previous answer. This is what I meant: I would use

> (@post.content).html_safe

because it is safer than using 'raw'.